# NUget package manager change directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am trying to install Entity Framework using the NUget package manager using the following command

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

but it is giving me the following error

> The term 'Install-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What I noticed is that on console I am getting

```
PS C:\Users\tz>  Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

I think it should be

```
PM  Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

If I am right how to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rare issue with the console initialization ([Issue #1953](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1953) in NuGet issue tracker) that should be fixed with the next version of Nuget (1.8).

As a work around restarting VS should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same behavior after upgrading to NuGet 1.7.

```
PS C:\Users\tz>
```

It fixed itself after rebooting the machine.